# Review: Delete or Recommend deletion

Tags: support

When reviewing Low Quality Posts why does my reviews become "Delete" when others say "Recommend Deletion". Is there a difference? Do I have more "power"?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you have more power since you're a [trusted user](/help/privileges/trusted-user). This means you can vote to delete answers with a score of -1<sup>*</sup> or lower, and three of those votes actually delete the post. Enough Recommend Deletion reviews will eventually delete the post as well, but six of those are needed (your Delete review counts towards those six as well).

For more information, you can read these Meta Stack Exchange topics:

- [When is a review task "completed" or "invalidated"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164288/295232)
- [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)

<sub>*: in the Low Quality Posts review queue, it's actually a score of 0 or lower</sub>